# variable, Comparison and Operators in powersehll

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0, powershell-remoting

I hope this question finds you well and healthy,

I have a powershell code, will list all the process in my computer with memory consumption in mb, it's working great for now, but the issue is I want to add the -gt operation to find only the processes with consumption greater than 100mb for example

```
Get-Process | Select-Object Name,@{Name='WorkingSet(MB)';Expression={($_.ws / 1024kb)}} | format-table -autosize
```

the result of this code is :

```
Name                                                          WorkingSet(MB)
----                                                          --------------
AppleMobileDeviceService                                          8.85546875
ApplicationFrameHost                                                32.40625
armsvc                                                             3.6328125
atmgr                                                            38.98828125
atmgr                                                            38.83984375
audiodg                                                           11.2109375
```

when im trying to add the -gt 100mb :

```
PS C:\Users\Documents> Get-Process | Select-Object Name,@{Name='WorkingSet(MB)';Expression={($_.ws / 1024kb) -gt 100}} | format-table -autosize

Name                                                          WorkingSet(MB)
----                                                          --------------
AppleMobileDeviceService                                               False
ApplicationFrameHost                                                   True
armsvc                                                                 False
atmgr                                                                  False
```

so the result is True or False, this is not my expectation because I want to have ONLY the processes with memory consumption more than 100 (the consumption must be mentioned not only true or false :/)

---

After solving this issue, my plan is put the script to be running every one hour, and log the output in case there is processes using more than 100mb, if yes, once I login to the laptop a popup warning message will appear using the bellow code :

```
powershell -WindowStyle hidden -Command "& {[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Windows.Forms'); [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show('Some Services are using more than 100mb of memory','WARNING')}"
```

I appreciate any idea or suggestions,

Can anyone help here, I really appreciate it.

Comment: After your `select-object`, add `| where {$_.'workingset(mb)' -gt 100}`

Comment: thank you it's working

Answer (score 0):

[Where-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-7.1) is a common way to filter objects based on their property values. When you pipe to `Select-Object`, you output a custom object based on its selected or calculated properties. You can filter your custom objects just like any other object output by another PowerShell command.

```
Get-Process |
    Select-Object Name,@{Name='WorkingSet(MB)';Expression={($_.ws / 1024kb)}} |
        Where-Object { $_.'WorkingSet(MB)' -gt 100 } |
            Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Note that the `Format-Table` command was moved to the end of the expression. `Format-*` commands should only be used for display purposes as they change the input object type.

Answer (score 0):

#You can do this  to get processes those are having more than 100MB

```
Get-Process |
    ? {(($_.ws/1mb) -ge 100) -eq $true} |
    select name, @{name = 'Memory';expression = {($_.ws/1mb)}}
```